# Remove SKUs from Magento PDFs

Tags: magento

I'm trying to remove the SKU number from the Invoice and Shipment PDFs in Magento, I've commented out all the references to SKU in the files located in app/code/local/mage/sales/model/order/pdf, but only the SKU header is gone, not the actual values.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I've looked through the code- I had edited the default renderer for invoice pdfs but it doesn't effect the code. I'm wondering if it's something to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overide the function draw() from the class

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Grouped
Mage_Bundle_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice
```

inorder to remove sku from invoice pdf.

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Shipment_Default
Mage_Bundle_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Shipment
```

inorder to remove sku from shipment pdf

Find the below code and comment it out

```
// draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 25),
            'feed'  => 440
        );
```

Comment: Thank you, we managed to work it out last minute that the bundle pdf templates were separately stored. Thanks for your help!